# CP2102N Short Between D+ and D-

Tags: usb, uart, short-circuit, cp2102

I am measuring a short between the D+ and D- lines between the USB micro connector and USB to UART chip (CP2102N). However by looking at the photos, there doesn't appear to be a short. Should I assume either a.) the chip is bad or b.) the pins are shorted underneath the chip?

The two pins of interest in the pictures are the ones connected by the two traces in the middle of the pictures.

This is a custom PCB for a project I'm working on. You can also see on the schematic, everything seems to be good.

I'm asking here before replacing the chip, because I currently do not have a hot air station, so removing will be a bit of effort.

Also, upon plugging in the board, I get the message: "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)" After discovering the short circuit, this message is hardly a surprise, but thought I would include that information.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A differential short is likely solder bridging. With both lines shorted to ground, it could be the IC or a solderbridge.

Comment: Neither pins are shorted to ground. That is a good theory though since the thermal ground pad underneath the chip is very close to the pads. I will update the post when I get the chip removed. I'm guessing the data lines were initially bridged when I plugged it in the first time and ruined the IC, so clearing the bridge was ineffective? Not sure.

Comment: i would suspect the USB connector first, since you interact with it mechanically ... remove it first ... less pins to de-solder ..... or cut one of the traces as suggested in the answer below

Comment: The active Tx over temp is 36 Ohms typ, yet the room temp Tx is 24 Ohms low and 40 Ohms high based on Vol/Iol or Voh (drop)/Ioh. So anything outside +/- 50% is unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say, but chances are if the chip is fried the short probably won't be as low resistance as if there is a solder short.

If it's more than a couple hundred milliohms I would suspect the chip.

You could also try butchering one of the traces to tie down where the short is.

Comment: I can't be too sure with my crappy multimeter, hovers around 0.1ohm, not enough resolution to provide any further meaning. I'll probably end up removing it. Also, confirmed on another unpopulated board that the traces are not shorted on their own due to the manufacturing of the board, but obviously one board could be different. I guess I'll play around with it more and see what happens, thanks for the suggestions.